# How to use "useContext" in typescript?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, use-state, use-context

I am trying to make a dark/light theme system in my project, but I am having some problems with the code.

This line of code works fine in javascript:

```
const [darktheme, setDarkTheme] = useContext(ThemeContext);
```

But when I write it into typescript, I get 6 errors.

I know that some of these variables need to have their type declared, but I only know the type of the darkTheme variable, which is a boolean.

After I declare the types, 2 errors go away, but there is still 4 errors!

```
const [darktheme: boolean, setDarkTheme: any] = useContext(ThemeContext);
```

*I used any after dark theme, which is not good practice but I didn't know the type*

Now I just get these errors:
[image]

[image]

I think that the main problem with my project is that I am trying to integrate javascript with typescript. I don't know if that is normal or not, but I am doing it because some components are much easier to write with typescript, and some more basic components are better written in javascript.

Here is part of my app.js:

```
// Context

export const ThemeContext = React.createContext();

function App() {
  const [darkTheme, setDarkTheme] = useState(false);

  return (
    <ThemeContext.Provider value={[darkTheme, setDarkTheme]}>
```

,and when I use the function in this component, it works just fine:

```
import React, { useContext } from 'react';
import { ThemeContext } from '../App';

import Button from 'react-bootstrap/Button';

export default function DarkThemeTest() {
    const [darktheme, setDarkTheme] = useContext(ThemeContext);

    return (
        <Button onClick={() => {
            setDarkTheme(!darktheme);
        }}>
            Theme: {darktheme && "Dark" || "Light"}
        </Button>
    )
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, define a type for your context value

```ts
import { createContext, Dispatch, SetStateAction } from "react";

interface ThemeContextType {
  darkTheme: boolean;

  // this is the type for state setters
  setDarkTheme: Dispatch<SetStateAction<boolean>>; 
}
```

Then, create your context with this type and initialise it with a default value. This might seem unnecessary but it will avoid checking for `null` or `undefined` context later on

```ts
export const ThemeContext = createContext<ThemeContextType>({
  darkTheme: false,
  setDarkTheme: () => {}, // no-op default setter
});
```

Once you have created your state value and setter, set them into the context provider value

```tsx
<ThemeContext.Provider value={{ darkTheme, setDarkTheme }}>
```

Now you can destructure the context value easily via `useContext` with full type support

```ts
const { darkTheme, setDarkTheme } = useContext(ThemeContext);
```

---

You could continue to use your array format though I wouldn't recommend it.

```ts
type ThemeContextType = [boolean, Dispatch<SetStateAction<boolean>>];

export const ThemeContext = createContext<ThemeContextType>([false, () => {}]);
```

and

```tsx
<ThemeContext.Provider value={[darkTheme, setDarkTheme]}>
```

Comment: I have one question, where do I use

const { darkTheme, setDarkTheme } = useContext(ThemeContext);

Currently, I am using it in the render() method, but it gives me this error:

React Hook "useContext" cannot be called in a class component. React Hooks must be called in a React function component or a custom React Hook function  react-hooks/rules-of-hooks

Comment: @JimmyGrant see the docs for using context in a class-based component ~ https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html#classcontexttype. I'd highly recommend moving those to function components though

Comment: () => {} causes eslint to complain "unexpected empty method"

Comment: @Daniel do you mean [no-empty-function](https://eslint.org/docs/latest/rules/no-empty-function)? Did you add the comment like in my answer?

Comment: @Phil yes that is what I mean. Didn't add the comment though. I didn't realize it was an eslint thing. I just did () => {""} which was accepted (kind of ugly though).

Comment: @Daniel you could always use something like `() => { console.warn("using context without provider"); }`