# Proper Use of React useContext?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-context

Trying to create a context that can store a username and will allow children to change/set said username. IDK if react updated recently but all of the tutorials online show `useContext()` with no parameters, but now it requires one and it makes setting the `value=[userName, setUserName]` worse. I keep getting the error "Type '(Dispatch<SetStateAction> | undefined)[]' is not assignable to type 'string'"

```
import React, { useState, createContext } from "react";
import { BrowserRouter, Routes, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';
import Home from './components/homepage/Home';
import Register from './components/register/Register';
import Post from './components/post/Post'; 
import Feed from './components/feed/Feed';

export const Context = createContext('');

function App() {

  const [userName, setUserName] = useState();

  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
    <Routes>
        <Route path="/" element={<Context.Provider value = {[userName, setUserName]}><Home /></Context.Provider>} />
        <Route path="/register" element={<Register />} />
        <Route path="/post" element={<Post />} />
        <Route path="/feed" element={<Feed />} />
    </Routes>
  </BrowserRouter>
  );
}

export default App;
```

I have tried this way as well to no avail.

```
// Create a new context and export
export const NameContext = createContext();
 
// Create a Context Provider
const NameContextProvider = ({ children }) => {
    const [name, setName] = useState(undefined);
 
    return (
        <NameContext.Provider value={{ name, setName }}>
            {children}
        </NameContext.Provider>
    );
};
```

Comment: _"the tutorials online show `useContext()` with no parameters"_... what tutorials? [The official one](https://react.dev/learn/passing-data-deeply-with-context#step-2-use-the-context) certainly passes the context as a parameter

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use "useContext" in typescript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73117229/how-to-use-usecontext-in-typescript). You've initialised your context with an empty string which defines the type it expects for the value. Define your context type correctly and supply a valid default value

Comment: I meant createContext(); with no parameters is what errors.

Answer (score -1):

Here's a simple demonstration of how you can use `useContext` for your project:

First, create your context file.

**NameContext.jsx**

```
export const NameContext = createContext();
 
const NameContextProvider = ({ children }) => {
    const [name, setName] = useState(undefined);
 
    return (
        <NameContext.Provider value={{ name, setName }}>
            {children}
        </NameContext.Provider>
    );
};
```

Wrap the components that need the values from the provider like so:

**App.jsx**

```
<NameContextProvider>
   //add whatever React component you want here that needs the values from 
     the above provider.
   </Sample>
</NameContextProvider>
```

Here's how you can use it inside:

**Sample.jsx**

```
const { name, setName } = useContext(NameContext)
```

Tip:
You can also create a function like so within your Context file so it's easier
to access and you don't need to call `useContext` each time you need the Context
Provider:

```
export function useNameContext():  {
  const context = useContext(NameContext);
  if (!context)
    throw new Error('some error message');
  return context;
}
```

Now it should look like this in your code:

```
const { name, setName } = useNameContext();
```

Hope this helps!